# WSO2IS - SAML Logout ERROR - No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes provided

Tags: session, saml, logout, amazon-iam, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to implement a Single Logout flow with WSO2IS SP1, but something seems to not work correctly.

I am trying to login on a Browser and then send a logout request on another Browser, to verify if the server-side session has been correctly disabled.

Specifically:

1. [BROWSER-1] Send Login SAML Request to RESIDENT IdP;
2. [BROWSER-1] Authenticate on RESIDENT IdP;
3. [BROWSER-1] Get "SessionIndex" from SAML Response;
4. [BROWSER-2] Send SAML Logout Request to RESIDENT IdP;
5. [BROWSER-1] Send Login SAML Request to RESIDENT IdP.

EXPECTED: User is not authenticated on BROWSER-1.

Unfortunately, on STEP 4 I get the following error:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-02-19 20:19:41,077] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor} -  No Established Sessions corresponding to Session Indexes provided. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-02-19 20:19:41,077] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO} -  Cache entry not found for Identity Provider LOCAL. Fetching entry from DB {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-02-19 20:19:41,082] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO} -  Entry fetched from DB for Identity Provider LOCAL. Updating cache {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO}
TID: [0] [IS] [2016-02-19 20:19:41,085] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Invalid SAML SSO Logout Request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet}
```

If I try to login/logout on the same browser, everything seems to work fine.

Can someone help me to correctly configure SAML Single Logout?
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Pellegrino

Comment: Looks like the WSO2 takes the session from the cookie (samlssoToken), not from the request :( During logout, the IS tries to use the client-less SLO (server-side), but apparently they simplified the session acquisition and takes the session from the cookie :/